# The solution of $x^x=2$ rational/algebraic irrational/transcendental?

Tags: tetration, transcendence-theory

What does the unique real number $x$ such that $x^x=2$ equal to? Is the value rational, algebraic irrational or transcendental?
What about $x^x=3$? Or $x^x=e$? $x^x=π$?

Answer (score 7):

The Gelfond-Schneider Theorem tells you that $x$ cannot be an algebraic irrational in the case of $2$ and $3$, but says nothing in the case of $e$ or $\pi$.  For elementary reasons $x$ could not be rational, since $(\frac{a}{b})^a=2^b$ is impossible as the right-hand side is an integer, and the left-hand side is not.  There may not be much else known.

Comment: For $x^x=e$, $x$ is necessarily transcendental, being equal to $\frac{1}{W(1)}$ where $W$ is the Lambert W function. $W(a)$ is transcendental for any algebraic $a$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  Follows from Lindemann-Weierstrass right?

Comment: Indeed. Not sure about the $x^x= \pi$ case though.

Comment: After thinking about it, in the case $x^x= \pi$, $x$ is, at the very least, irrational: assuming otherwise that $x= \frac{m}{n}$, we quickly obtain $\pi^n= x^m$, so $\pi$ would then have to be algebraic, which it isn't.

Comment: sharding4 why can't the left hand side of that equation be an integer?

Comment: @curious  You can assume $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime, so $gcd(a,b)=1$.  Then $gcd(a^a,b^a)=1$  It should be clear that $x^x=2$ could not have an integer solution, so a rational solution would have to be $\frac{a}{b}$

Comment: I've managed to cover the cases of $e$ and more general, $e^q,q\in\mathbb Q$.  See my new answer :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt  Looks good.  Seems like the $x^x=\pi$ is going to be pretty intractable.

Answer (score 4):

One may find solutions in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

$$x^x=a\\\ln(x)e^{\ln(x)}=\ln(a)\\\ln(x)=W(\ln(a))\\x=e^{W(\ln(a))}=\frac{\ln(a)}{W(\ln(a))}$$

In the case that we are solving $x^x=e$, we find that

$$x=e^{W(1)}=e^\Omega=\frac1\Omega$$

where $\Omega$ is the [Omega constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omega_constant), which is known to be transcendental, thus $x$ is transcendental.  It follows directly from the [Lindemann-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) that if $\frac1\Omega$ were algebraic, then $e^\Omega$ would be transcendental, a contradicition, so $\Omega$ must be transcendental.

Similar arguments may be constructed to show that if $a=e^t$ for algebraic $t$, then $x$ is transcendental.